# How to unfold lines in insert mode?

Tags: folding

`zo` can open folded lines in normal mode. What if I'm in insert mode?

For example:

```
line1
line2
```

Fold it with `:1,2fold` in ex mode; now, the cursor is in the beginning of line1. Then press `o` to switch to insert mode, move the cursor to the beginning of line1, press `z`, and the content will turn into this:

```
line1
zline2
```

How to unfold lines in insert mode instead of adding the character `z`?

Comment: You said: *"press `o` to switch to insert mode, **move the cursor** to the beginning of line1, ..."* This seems to be the source of the issue. Normally you'd want to go back to Normal mode to move back to line 1. When you do so, it should be easy to unfold (or fold) lines as you need to access the ones you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In insert mode,move the cursor on to the folded line ,press leftwards or rightwards arrow or enter key  to unfold it.

Comment: I am sorry for that , forget it ,closed now.

Answer (score 2):

With `Ctrl-o` you can switch from Insert to Normal mode for the duration of one command.

So if in Insert mode, `Ctrl-o` `zo` opens the fold and brings you back into Insert mode again.